# JUnit test with Cobertura Coverage Report

Tags: java, junit, cobertura

I am writing a JUnit test case for a method and I am getting 50% branch coverage on it. I've tried both conditions (Null and !Null) but no luck.

Method under test:

```
private List<IClientFilter> clientFilters;
public void addFilter( IClientFilter cf ) {
    if( clientFilters == null ) {
        clientFilters = new ArrayList<IClientFilter>();
    }
    clientFilters.add( cf );
}
```

JUnit test:

```
@Test
public void testAddFilter() throws ESignatureClientException, Exception {
    IClientFilter clientFilter = new ESignatureClientFilter();

    new ClientConfiguration().addFilter(clientFilter);

    List<IClientFilter> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add(clientFilter);

    assertNotNull(list);
    assertFalse(list.isEmpty());
    assertEquals(1, list.size());
}
```

Cobertura is not covering the if condition even if clientFilters == null

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

To have 100% coverage on this method, you should call `addFilter` two times :

1. The first time will create the `clientFilters` list
2. The second time will use the existing `clientFilters`

Calling this methods two times will test that the lazy list `clientFilters` is created effectively